# Return previous page after submitting my form && my js have side effect

Tags: javascript

i have a side effect when i return at previous page after submitting my form.

This fields have default values, and i check if the first value havn't it default value to remove the seconde value.

My JS:

```
    let firstValue = document.getElementById('client').value;

    function removeCurrentValue(){
        if(document.getElementById('first_value').value.length <= 0 && firstValue === 255) {
            return document.getElementById('customer').value = '';
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        removeCurrentValue();
    });

    document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = function () {
        removeCurrentValue();
    }
```

my html is basic just fields have default value.

When i submit again i have client=255 in my header but i dont want it !

I cant console.log in removeCurrentValue() condition but values have a good comportment

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+reset+form+back+button+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: What excatly is the problem? What is the side effect?

Comment: when i submit again i have the client=255 in my header